# In PHP What Is The @ Symbol Placed In Front Of A Param Name Used For?

Tags: php, json, api

I have come across this a few times, but have never used or understood why it happens or what it's actually for.

In some APIs i have used that return an object, converted then from JSON to a PHP object, some of the parameter names have an @ symbol in front of them.

A normal object would generally be like:

```
Object{
    param:'Hello'
}
```

But in some cases it's like this:

```
Object{
    @param:'Hello'
}
```

So what is the @ for and how did it get there? Never really come across this while coding myself except from some external api data.

Comment: Folks can name their parameters anything. Just means the originating JSON is `{"@param":"Hello"}`. `{"@@@@@@!":"Hello"}` would be just as valid. Stupid, but valid. Ask the folks who made the API - maybe it means something specific to their API, but it has no formal meaning for PHP/JSON.

Comment: Just another parameter name, the symbol can also be used to [silence error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) but don't do that... please.

Comment: ok, rather strange way of doing it, seems really pointless and just makes handling it on the other end more difficult. It makes more sense to access via $object->param than $object->{'@param'}

Comment: oh yeh i know it is used for silencing errors, but in this particular example it seems totally pointless

Comment: @GlenElkins Yeah, it's poorly chosen. Perhaps it means something like "this is a deprecated param" or "this parameter can't be edited" or whatnot, but that's entirely up to the folks running the API.

Comment: thanks guys , made me feel better now lol

Comment: It can be used at times to emulate the way that XPath handles attributes, so in XML it may be `<a href="ppp">` XPath uses `@href` to refer to the attribute.